# Tacking Inventory onto a customer in SQL

Tags: php, sql, join

I have the following code that shows me and allows me to search within a products table/ or a customers table.  I would like to know how I can associate certain products with certain customers, as if I am creating an invoice, within php.
[image: Visual Representation]

```
 if(isset($_POST['q'])) {

$q = $_POST['q'];

$select = $db->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE Model LIKE '%$q%' OR Description LIKE '%$q%' ORDER BY id DESC");

} else {

$select = $db->query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id DESC");

}
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="q" /> <input type="submit" name="search" />
</form>
```

Comment: you'll need to track which user made the purchase and which product was bought, you'll probably need those respective IDs in there

Comment: JOINS http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Comment: You'll need a link table between invoices and products.

Comment: [here](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm) is a bit of info about normalizing databases, this should also help when you want to do what you are trying to do, and combine this with `joins`

Comment: I understand I need a link between the tables, can anyone demonstrate a code sample I could play with that would allow me to attach multiple items to an invoice, while at the same time having the invoice attached to a customer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Very Simplified Order Form and Order Entry:

I use buttons rather than div for formatting columns in rows because `<button>` default display is `inline-block` and they are easy to style.  I often use them to supply additional info when they are clicked. (`onclick`)
**Test Database Tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Invoice` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `customer` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Items` (
  `Invoice` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `qty` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Model` char(16) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `Description` char(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `Cost` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,
  `Retail` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
INSERT INTO `Products` (`id`, `Model`, `Description`, `Cost`, `Retail`) VALUES
(1, 'Model 1', 'Model 1', '0.50', '1.00'),
(2, 'Model 2', 'Model 2', '1.00', '2.00');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Customer` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` char(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
INSERT INTO `Customer` (`id`, `Name`) VALUES
(1, 'Customer Name');
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Invoice` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

PHP HTML form:
**Tested.**

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db");
$customer = 1;
echo <<<EOT
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><title>Order</title><meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=1.0" />
<style type="text/css">
.desc{border:0;width:15em;}
.model{border:0;width:5em;}
.price{border:0;width:5em;}
</style></head><body><div id="page"><div id="page">
<form action="" method="post"><div>
<button class="go" type="submit">Back</button>
<input type="hidden" name="customer" value="$customer" />
</div></form>
<form action="order.php" method="post"><div>
Customer: <input type="number" name="customer" value="$customer" /><br/><br/>

EOT;
$sql = "SELECT `ID`,`Model`,`Description`,`Retail` FROM `Products` WHERE 1  ORDER BY `Description` LIMIT 25";
$results = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if (mysqli_errno($conn) > 0){echo mysqli_error($conn) . "<br/>\n$sql\n";}
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_NUM)){
  echo "<input type=\"number\" name=\"q$row[0]\" />&#x2002;<button class=\"model\" type=\"button\">$row[1]</button>&#x2002;<button class=\"desc\" type=\"button\">$row[2]</button>&#x2002;<button class=\"price\" type=\"button\">$row[3]</button><br/>";
}
echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit"></div></form></body></html>';
?>
```

The PHP the form is submitted to:
**Tested**

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db");
echo <<<EOT
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><title>Order</title><meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=1.0" />
<style type="text/css">

</style></head><body><div id="page"><div id="page">
EOT;
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
  $type = substr($key,0,1);
  $id = substr($key,1);
  $pair[$type][$id] = intval($value);
}
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `Invoice` (`ID`,`customer`) VALUES(NULL,$customer)";
  $results = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  if (mysqli_errno($conn) > 0){echo mysqli_error($conn) . "<br/>\n$sql\n";}
  $invoice =  mysqli_insert_id ($conn );
  echo "<h3>Invoice: $invoice</h3>";
foreach ($pair['q'] as $id => $qty){
  echo "<p>Qty: $qty id: $id,</p>";
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `Items` (`Invoice`,`product`,`qty`) VALUES($invoice,$id,$qty)";
  $results = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  if (mysqli_errno($conn) > 0){echo mysqli_error($conn) . "<br/>\n$sql\n";}

}
echo '</div></body></html>';
?>
```

Comment: How would I alter your code to allow for the calling of my database connection as I have it now?  I use "require 'db/connect.php';" to connnect to the database.  I have tried adding this, but something in the code, more specifically this line : "echo "<input type=\"number\" name=\"q$row[0]\" />&#x2002;<button type=\"button\">$row[1]</button>&#x2002;<button type=\"button\">$row" says there is an unexpected "type" used.  In addition, is the php that the form submitted to "order.php" or "customer.php", and either or, what goes in the other php file?

Comment: BTW : I have a products table, and a customers table, I do not know how my invoices table needs to be setup

Comment: I added the Invoice and Items database CREATE queries.  copy the first two (create invoice and create items) into your query box (e.g. phpMyAdmin)  and execute.

Comment: I just finished updating the two PHP scripts.  Both tested.

Comment: I get this with the above code : "Undefined variable: customer", for this line : "<form action="submit.php" method="post"><div>"  I think I need a way to select from the form fields both a customer(from the customer table), and a specifiic item(from the products table) instead of listing every item at once and upping the qty on each item(could be over 100,1000, etc items)

Comment: I added a LIMIT 25 to the product SELECT query.  And made the customer `<input` a numeric entry field.  You have to try and do some of this.  Add a search form to the HTML.  Use a different SELECT query when a search is submitted.

Comment: Brilliant!  I never thought to have a fourth table that would hold values pointing in that way.  I will have to do a little research to figure out the way you used $key and $value.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74744/discussion-between-misunderstood-and-steven).